# Bootstrap tooltip keep position when using a CSS transform animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, css-transforms

I am using bootstrap Vue tooltips. I would like to add a custom CSS animation on the tooltip when it is shown.

However, when I add an animation that uses transform, the tooltip will be shown at the top left of the screen, and when the transform animation is over, it is returned to the correct position.

My code is:

```
<div id="app">
  <b-button :ref="uniqueRef" class="m-5">
    Click Me
  </b-button>
   <b-tooltip :target="() => $refs[uniqueRef]" title="This is cool" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes tada {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  10%,
  20% {
    transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }

  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.tooltip {
  animation: tada 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

I created a minimal reproducible example here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/dgeerts/pen/xxQxQvZ)

Comment: Your animation is probably overwriting some transform (a translate) which positions the tooltip.

Comment: Do you mean a translate done by bootstrap internally? Because in my code example I cannot see it written anywhere. How do I start debugging this?

Comment: Have you tried your browser's devtools inspect facility? You can see the translate being applied when the tooltip appears.

Comment: I am not sure how to inspect this. Since putting hover, focus or anything via the inspector on the button does not seem to trigger the tooltip. So inspecting the css becomes tedious since it dissapears from the dom the second I move my mouse off the tooltip. I guess the translate is a bootstrap default for positioning the tooltip correctly. So it's not possible to put the animation as in my code pen to appear in the correct position?

Comment: I hovered over the element rather than the tooltip and saw the tooltip element appearing a few lines down in the elements. There was a transform translate there in the style attribute values.